# regex over maximum amount of lines

Tags: regex, pcre

I have some regex that is matching lines I do not want included. I have tried to use a positive and negative lookahead but I couldn't quite understand it fully. Instead I was wondering if there was an option to only match over a max number of lines e.g. 4?

My partially working regex is:

```
TLS 1.1 Cipher suites(?s).*?The server accepted
```

The problem is it is including the first 7 lines, which I do not want to be included. I only want it to include lines 11-14 in the text below:

```
 * TLS 1.1 Cipher suites:
     Attempted to connect using 80 cipher suites; the server rejected all cipher suites.

 * TLS 1.2 Cipher suites:
     Attempted to connect using 158 cipher suites.

     The server accepted the following 4 cipher suites:
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384             256       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)

 * TLS 1.1 Cipher suites:
     Attempted to connect using 15 cipher suites.

     The server accepted the following 2 cipher suites:
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                256       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: So you want to get the last match of a file, am I right ?

Comment: Not exactly, I only want to match the string over 4 lines in length. In this example, it is matching the first 7 lines (which I don't want)

Comment: I think you should be able to use a positive lookahead that matches 4 lines `(?=(?:.*\n){4})`

Comment: You also need a *negative* lookahead that prevents it from including multiple blocks.

Comment: Do you have to do this just with a regexp? It seems like it would be easier to first split up the input into blocks, then filter the blocks to the ones that match your criteria.

Comment: Otherwise, maybe: `TLS 1\.1 Cipher suites[^*]*The server accepted`?

Comment: magic! that works @JvdV. many thanks!! thanks all for your wonderful help )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, it seems you want to match both 'TLS 1.1 Cipher suites' and 'The server accepted' in a single "block". Therefor I was thinking to negate an literal asterisk:

```
TLS 1\.1 Cipher suites[^*]*The server accepted
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QaFWIu/6)

Not sure what your intention is further down the line with the matched substring. A small note, if you want to match a literal dot, you need to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: thanks so much once again!! i don't have enough points to upvote you, otherwise i would!